# Apache mod_rewrite to Nginx

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, nginx

Not sure how to change this to nginx mod_rewrite, tried http://winginx.com/en/htaccess but no success.

Apache rewrite is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Anyone help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
proxy_set_header HTTP_AUTHORIZATION $http_authorization;

if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_1 1$rule_1;
}
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_1 2$rule_1;
}
if ($rule_1 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/ /index.php last;
}
if ($http_authorization ~ "."){
    set $rule_2 1$rule_2;
}
```